# Read target of symlink and increment target by one

Tags: shell, scripting, symlink

I have a folder structure that looks like this

```
/some/folder/1
/some/folder/2
...
```

and a symlink `current` that links to one of the folders. Is it possible and when how to read the target of the link, increment the name of the last folder and create a folder with that number, e.g. read the link that points to `/some/folder/2` so I know the last number is `2` and increment this number to create a new folder `/some/folder/3` to store new files?

I already have a script that reads the target of the link, but I have no clue how to get the last part of the path (the number) and increment it by one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `readlink` to get the target of a symlink:

```
target=$(readlink $1)
```

then use the power of shell, to remove everything before the last `/`;

```
id=${target##*/}
```

or remove everything after the last `/`:

```
base=${target%/*}
```

then use the power of shell to do simple arithmetic

```
newid=$((id+1))
```

finally glue them together:

```
newtarget=${base}/${newid}
```

or, in one line:

```
newtarget=${target%/*}/$((${target##*/}+1))
```

Comment: It's good practice to reserve all-uppercase variables to environment variables.

Comment: That won't work if the link is like `current -> 2` (as would be the most sensible thing to do). Use `base=${target%"$id"}` and `newtarget=$base$newid` instead.

Comment: but the latter case is trivial anyhow: `newtarget=$(($(readlink current) + 1 ))`

Comment: Using `dirname` and `basename` would also make it more robust (also for cases where the link is like `current -> 2/`)